# How is my class breaking encapsulation?

Tags: object-oriented, encapsulation

I was submitting this code in Java to an AI tool that checks for OOPS modeling and it says that this class is breaking encapsulation, although it did not gave any reason why.

The objective is to store the three types of subscription for a user (music, video or podcast) and add a topup only if atleast one type of subscription is added. You can only add subscription or topup only after providing a valid start date, otherwise you must print the error messages. The code is giving correct outputs as required by the problem, but it does not satisfy the bot's OOPS modelling criteria. Can anybody explain why that might be?

```
public class UserSubscriptionService {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    private LocalDate subscriptionStartDate;
    private Subscription musicSubscription;
    private Subscription videoSubscription;
    private Subscription podcastSubscription;
    private Subscription topUp;

    public UserSubscriptionService() {
        this.subscriptionStartDate = null;
        this.musicSubscription = null;
        this.videoSubscription = null;
        this.podcastSubscription = null;
        this.topUp = null;
    }

    private void printRenewalReminderForSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
        if (subscriptionStartDate == null) return;

        LocalDate reminderDate = subscriptionStartDate
                .plusMonths(subscription.getPeriodMonths())
                .minusDays(Constants.REMINDER_DAYS_AGO);

        System.out.println("RENEWAL_REMINDER\t" + subscription.getType().name() + "\t" + reminderDate.format(dateFormatter));
    }

    private Subscription createMusicSubscription(String plan) {
        if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.FREE.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.MUSIC, SubscriptionPlan.FREE, Constants.MUSIC_FREE_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.MUSIC_FREE_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.MUSIC, SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL, Constants.MUSIC_PERSONAL_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.MUSIC_PERSONAL_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.MUSIC, SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM, Constants.MUSIC_PREMIUM_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.MUSIC_PREMIUM_PLAN_COST);

        return null;
    }

    private Subscription createVideoSubscription(String plan) {
        if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.FREE.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.VIDEO, SubscriptionPlan.FREE, Constants.VIDEO_FREE_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.VIDEO_FREE_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.VIDEO, SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL, Constants.VIDEO_PERSONAL_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.VIDEO_PERSONAL_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.VIDEO, SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM, Constants.VIDEO_PREMIUM_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.VIDEO_PREMIUM_PLAN_COST);

        return null;
    }

    private Subscription createPodcastSubscription(String plan) {
        if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.FREE.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.PODCAST, SubscriptionPlan.FREE, Constants.PODCAST_FREE_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.PODCAST_FREE_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.PODCAST, SubscriptionPlan.PERSONAL, Constants.PODCAST_PERSONAL_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.PODCAST_PERSONAL_PLAN_COST);
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM.toString()))
            return new Subscription(SubscriptionType.PODCAST, SubscriptionPlan.PREMIUM, Constants.PODCAST_PREMIUM_PLAN_VALIDITY, Constants.PODCAST_PREMIUM_PLAN_COST);

        return null;
    }

    private boolean hasSubscriptions() {
        return (musicSubscription!=null || videoSubscription!=null || podcastSubscription!=null);
    }

    private boolean hasSubscriptionOfType(String type) {
        if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.MUSIC.toString())) return this.musicSubscription != null;
        if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.VIDEO.toString())) return this.videoSubscription!=null;
        if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.PODCAST.toString())) return this.podcastSubscription!=null;
        if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.TOPUP.toString())) return this.topUp!=null;
        return false;
    }

    public void addSubscription(String type, String plan) {
        if (this.subscriptionStartDate == null) {
            System.out.println("ADD_SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED\tINVALID_DATE");
            return;
        }

        if (hasSubscriptionOfType(type)) {
            System.out.println("ADD_SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED\tDUPLICATE_CATEGORY");
            return;
        }

        if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.MUSIC.toString()))
            musicSubscription = createMusicSubscription(plan);
        else if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.VIDEO.toString()))
            videoSubscription = createVideoSubscription(plan);
        else if (type.equals(SubscriptionType.PODCAST.toString()))
            podcastSubscription = createPodcastSubscription(plan);
    }

    public void addTopUp(String plan, int duration) {
        if (this.subscriptionStartDate == null) {
            System.out.println("ADD_TOPUP_FAILED\tINVALID_DATE");
            return;
        }

        if (!hasSubscriptions()) {
            System.out.println("ADD_TOPUP_FAILED\tSUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_FOUND");
            return;
        }

        if (this.topUp != null) {
            System.out.println("ADD_TOPUP_FAILED\tDUPLICATE_TOPUP");
            return;
        }

        if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.FOUR_DEVICE.toString())) {
            this.topUp = new Subscription(SubscriptionType.TOPUP, SubscriptionPlan.FOUR_DEVICE, duration, Constants.FOUR_DEVICE_TOPUP_COST);
        }
        else if (plan.equals(SubscriptionPlan.TEN_DEVICE.toString())) {
            this.topUp = new Subscription(SubscriptionType.TOPUP, SubscriptionPlan.TEN_DEVICE, duration, Constants.TEN_DEVICE_TOPUP_COST);
        }
    }

    public void setSubscriptionStartDate(String date) {
        try {
            this.subscriptionStartDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateFormatter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("INVALID_DATE");
        }
    }

    public void printRenewalDetails() {
        if (!hasSubscriptions()) {
            System.out.println("SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_FOUND");
        }

        if (musicSubscription != null) { printRenewalReminderForSubscription(musicSubscription); }
        if (videoSubscription != null) { printRenewalReminderForSubscription(videoSubscription); }
        if (podcastSubscription != null) { printRenewalReminderForSubscription(podcastSubscription); }
    }

    public void printSubscriptionRenewalCost() {
        if (subscriptionStartDate==null) return;

        long cost = 0;

        if (this.musicSubscription!=null)
            cost += this.musicSubscription.getCost();

        if (this.videoSubscription!=null)
            cost += this.videoSubscription.getCost();

        if (this.podcastSubscription!=null)
            cost += this.podcastSubscription.getCost();

        if (this.topUp != null)
            cost += this.topUp.getCost() * this.topUp.getPeriodMonths();

        System.out.println("RENEWAL_AMOUNT\t" + cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: That AI tool either has significantly more or significantly less intelligence than I have. But without telling you what is wrong, it is useless.

Comment: "although it did not gave any reason why" Then drop the tool, it's totally pointless to use it.

Comment: My best guess is that the AI has perhaps been trained to detect if you have a bunch of getters and setters named the same way as your private fields (cause a get/set pair per field exposes the internal structure), and that it goes by the naming pattern, but that it didn't realize that your `createXyzSubscription` methods are private. So could just be a false positive. But as others have said, without a reason or an explanation of some sort, it's not of much use.

Comment: A get/set pair doesn't expose anything about the internals. I can easily change the internals and leave the getters / setters unchanged.

Comment: Not related to your question, but hasSubscriptionOfType looks like it has copy/paste errors checking for MUSIC more than once

Comment: refactor out all the if blocks by having a dictionary of subscriptions and see if it still compains

Comment: @gnasher729 "I can easily change the internals and leave the getters / setters unchanged" - In theory, you could, but what actually happens is that people don't think enough about the interface when they design the class, so client code gets written in a way where it's coupled to (or comes to expect) those fields, and then when a change comes that renders some of those fields and corresponding getters and setters obsolete/redundant/meaningless, you have to change both the interface *and* client code in a nontrivial way. It breaks the "tell don't ask" principle.

Comment: @nvoigt i would have dropped it if I was just personally using it, this tool is a part of code evaluation for a hiring website.

Comment: `But without telling you what is wrong, it is useless`. Even if it does, it's most likely useless. It reminds me of SonarQube and most of its default rules. No AI or static analysis can decide if your code is right or wrong. Even when it tells why "is wrong" , the reasons must be interpreted according to the context. Like coupling, the coupling will always exist but we decide where and when. That's subjective and has to be interpreted within a context.

Comment: @AyushKumar , not related to the question but, If you are applying as Java developer, it would be good that you follow Java's coding conventions. Private methods, always, go last. Move public instance methods to the top, right after the constructor, then protected and privates. Static methods go last, also in the same order (public, protected, private).

Comment: I don't see anything that breaks encapsulation.  I'm wondering if there's something about Subscription that may explain this.  A lot of these tools use the compiled bytecodes and that might confuse the tool about where the offending code is actually found in source.

Comment: The tool might be mistaking the private methods for public ones somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Every class breaks encapsulation to some extent. The question that a real person needs to answer is "is this problem worth worrying about **for my specific use case**?"

To pick two examples from your code which *could* be considered as breaking encapsulation:

- `printRenewalReminderForSubscription` does two tasks: working out if a reminder is necessary, and then outputting that reminder to the console. This doesn't feel reusable in a generic system where your users probably won't be attached to the local console. (Repeat for all other uses of `System.out`)
- `setSubscriptionStartDate` both parses a date and sets the date. You've tied yourself to the local date format which again probably isn't what you want for a generic system.

However, I again reiterate that these may be fine given your requirements.

Comment: How `doesn't feel reusable in a generic system` and `you've tied yourself to the local date format` breaks encapsulation?

Answer (score 0):

I have no insight as why or where this unknown tools detects what.

That said, there are two large areas, that raise some red flags to me, maybe one was detected by the tool:

- Large parts of your code are "stringly typed". Means you expect Strings as parameters and then you hope and pray they match your actual strong types. Java is a "Strongly typed" language. Drop the String nonsense. If you *have* a type `SubscriptionType`, then **use it**. This would also probably cut your code size in half. Code you do not have is code that cannot contain bugs and does not have to be maintained.
- `setSubscriptionStartDate` is a weird method. There should be no such method. `startDate` should be a parameter to the `addSubscription` method. As should probably "endDate". And it should be saved with the subscription, in case you want to top it up.

If I had to guess, I would say the tool detected the last point. Not sure If I agree with the "breaks encapsulation", I would go with "just wrong".

Comment: "If you have a type SubscriptionType" this would appear to be an ideal use-case for typesafe enums and it would indeed reduce the amount of code greatly.